# The equations doesn't display in a word(*.docx) document that converted from a markdown file using knitr

Tags: ms-word, knitr, mathjax, pandoc

Environment: win7 64bit; pandoc; RStudio; knitr
Microsoft Office Word 2007

Code:

```
<!--pandoc
t: html
s:
mathjax:
number-sections:
bibliography: foo.bib
o: output.html
-->
---
title: "test06"
author: "Franklin"
date: "Tuesday, June 24, 2014"
output: word_document
---

Some mathematics:

$$
  e^{(i\pi)}+1 = 0
$$

Inline test $\sin(x)$.
```

I typed the commands in the Console of RStudio as below,

> pandoc('test05.md', format='docx')

While the equations in the word document don't display at all.

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/103